# Postgres: Get the list of updated columns in FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

We have an expensive `AFTER UPDATE...FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger function that populates a `tsvector` column for search.

There is a subset of columns that are searchable and part of the `tsvector` generation.

Since we can't specify the column list in `CREATE TRIGGER` for statement level triggers, is there a way to figure out the columns that were updated against the current `UPDATE` statement so we regenerate the `tsvector` only when one of the searchable columns is updated?

Edit: The `UPDATE` statement can update 1 or 50K row in one go.

Edit2: Seems like the duplicate of the following question. I will keep this open for sometime just in any new function was added to Postgres later on.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290005/how-to-select-sub-object-with-given-keys-from-jsonb

Comment: Trying creating a trigger f unction that will check if any of the specified columns have changed. If they have, it will proceed to update the tsvector column. If not, it will do nothing.  Within the function, use IF statements to compare the NEW and OLD values for each column you're interested in.

Use IF Statements: Within the function, use IF statements to compare the NEW and OLD values for each column you're interested in.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com Thank you. How I exactly check if the specified columns are changes. It's a FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger and the NEW and OLD are the collection of rows updated. Are you saying, somehow iterate over all rows and check for each relavent column if it's changed or not for each row? Cosidering the fact that the UPDATE statement can update upto 50K rows in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if specific columns have changed in a PostgreSQL trigger using transition tables, you can iterate over each pair of old and new rows and use the `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator to compare the values of the relevant columns. Here's a simplified example of how this can be done within the trigger function:

```
FOR row_old, row_new IN
    SELECT old.*, new.*
    FROM old_table AS old
    JOIN new_table AS new ON old.primary_key = new.primary_key
LOOP
    -- Check if any of the relevant columns have changed
    IF row_old.searchable_column1 IS DISTINCT FROM row_new.searchable_column1
       OR row_old.searchable_column2 IS DISTINCT FROM row_new.searchable_column2
       -- Add more columns as needed
    THEN
        -- Perform tsvector update logic here
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

**USING TRIGGER**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_trigger_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    row_old RECORD;
    row_new RECORD;
    is_changed BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    -- Iterate over each pair of old and new rows
    FOR row_old, row_new IN
        SELECT * FROM old_table
        JOIN new_table ON old_table.primary_key = new_table.primary_key
    LOOP
        -- Check if any of the relevant columns have changed
        is_changed := row_old.searchable_column1 IS DISTINCT FROM row_new.searchable_column1
                   OR row_old.searchable_column2 IS DISTINCT FROM row_new.searchable_column2
                   -- Add more columns as needed
                   ;

        -- Update tsvector if there is a change in relevant columns
        IF is_changed THEN
            -- Perform tsvector update logic here
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON my_table
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table NEW TABLE AS new_table
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE FUNCTION my_trigger_function();
```